# Very elementary set theory inquiry

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{N} E_i$ and $B = \bigcup_{j=1}^{N} F_j $. Does it follow that

$$ A \cap B = \bigcup_{i=1}^{N} \bigcup_{j=1}^{N} (E_i \cap F_j) = \bigcup_{j=1}^{N} \bigcup_{i=1}^{N} (E_i \cap F_j)$$

?????

Comment: Yes. !!!!!$\!\!$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the distributive property? Namely, that $(A \cup B) \cap C = (A \cap C) \cup (B \cap C)$?  If, so all you need to do is expand the expression with some careful algebra.  I will do it for collections of $3$ sets and maybe you can try and do it for $N$ sets. You could either do this directly, or using induction (induction may give you less of a headache).

So say $A = E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3$ and $B = F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3$ then
$$A \cap B = (E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3) \cap (F_1 \cup F_2 \cup F_3)$$
$$=((E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3) \cap F_1) \cup ((E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3) \cap F_2) \cup ((E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3) \cap F_3) $$
$$=((E_1 \cap F_1) \cup (E_2 \cap F_1) \cup (E_3 \cap F_1)) \cup ((E_1 \cap F_2) \cup (E_2 \cap F_2) \cup (E_3 \cap F_2)) \cup ((E_1 \cap F_3) \cup (E_2 \cap F_3) \cup (E_3 \cap F_3))$$
$$=\bigcup_{i=1}^3 (E_i \cap F_1) \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^3 (E_i \cap F_2) \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^3 (E_i \cap F_3)$$

And then we get:
$$ A \cap B = \bigcup_{j=1}^3 \bigcup_{i=1}^3 (E_i \cap F_j)$$

Similarly, by distributing the other way you get 
$$A \cap B = \bigcup_{i=1}^3 \bigcup_{j=1}^3 (E_i \cap F_j)$$

Comment: I think there is a mistake here.  Let $E_1 = E_2 = E_3 = V$. Then the union of the $F_i$'s somehow turns into the intersection of the $F_i$'s.

Comment: Apparently, I don't know the distributive property! Let me fix that...